# Passing parameters in mvp pattern

Tags: gwt, cordova, mvp

This might be a general mvp places and activities question, but the show case I'm trying to understand here is this [`gwtphonegap-showcase-gwt` example](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/RunningShowcase).

How do I pass a parameter to a view from another one?

For example, let's say I want that when a user clicks on any cell on the `OverviewActivity`, it will take them to the same place everytime (`AboutPlace`), but the text should be different (let's say it contains the cell number).

I added a `setText(String text)` to the `AboutDisplay` interface with the corresponding label and `setText()` in the `AboutDisplayGwtImpl`, but I have no idea where to call it. I tried calling it in `AboutActivity` `start()` method and `ClientFactoryGwtImpl` `getAboutDisplay()` method, but they seem to be called only once when the app first loads, so I end up with the same text each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use a view directly for that.

You can add a field on a place and set your value there and access the same value in the next activity.

Comment: that's exatly what i did: field on the view, the place sets the text.
but it seems the place just sets the text only once, and never after that.

Comment: the place should not set anything. with your first activty you create a new place with a field on it containing the data. The second activity reads that place and updates its view accordingly